# how to update google play services version in library ( .aar ) file

Tags: android, google-play-services

Currently i am working on beacon setup in android app. One of my third-party library(.aar) use lower version of **google-play-services** and it is not compatible with app play-services. Is there a way to update **google-play-services** library in **.aar**

Comment: You can try to update the aar from this repo:https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-base. I think the google play service in aar is in your 3-rd party library, you may send a request to them or just change to another library which perform the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up failing to update play store version of **.aar** library file unless I request to library support team. I solved my issue using play store version which okay for both of the libraries .